# Optimize code to get text from previous "td" using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I am trying to get text from previous `td` using id of input field. Below is my HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td class="fieldLabel">
        <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">
            <span class="redColor">*</span>" Contact number "
        </label>
    </td>
    <td class="fieldValue">
        <input id="contact_number" type="text" class="input-large" name="contact_number" value="">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, using id of input field which is `contact_number`, I have to get the text from previous `td` of it. Now, I am using below `jQuery` code to get it.

```
var labelText = $('#contact_number').closest('td').prev('td').find('label').text().replace('*', '').trim();
```

Now, this above code works fine, but it takes almost 1 second(not exactly, but it takes time). Now, I want to know, is there a way to optimize it to work faster. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way that script takes 1 second to execute. Even 10ms would be a push. In jQuery that's about all you can do. If you want faster then use native JS methods, but if the page is *that* slow then you have much bigger problems either with the DOM, or the hardware of the machine viewing it.

Comment: I have analyzed, but it takes more that 10ms, I am damn sure. Might be issue with server. But other things work fine

Comment: This is JS. The server is irrelevant.

Comment: ok, as per you, there is no way to optimize it. Thanks anyway. I just wanted to check, is there any way to achieve it. No issue. Thanks again.

Comment: You could use native JS, as I mentioned above, but the main point is that no single line of DOM-amending logic, either native JS or jQuery, should take longer than ~100ms. If it does, then there are some other severe problems you need to fix first.

Comment: ok, I'll look into other problems as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var labelText = $('#contact_number').prev('label').text().replace('*', '').trim();
```